# How far away do I need to be away from guards and sound bugs to avoid being heard?

Tags: invisible-inc

Using lethal weapons and sprinting will create noise, which will alert guards to your location. There are frequently times where I'm not sure if I can safely sprint through that room without alerting the guards, or if I'll just broadcast the location of my agents to everyone. I've tried doing some SCIENCE! to figure out the distance myself, but I'm playing on Expert mode I don't really have much room for SCIENCE! without it backfiring.

How far away do I need to be from guards and sound bugs to avoid being detected when I make noise by sprinting or firing lethal weapons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Incognita program **Ping** allows you to create a noise at a location of your choosing, for the purposes of distracting guards. When using this, you can see the radius of the sound it will create, and this has a 5-tile range that is kind of circular (you know, as much as possible on a square grid).

It looks like this (also, note how the sound will pass through walls unimpeded):
[image: Clipped screenshot showing highlight area of Ping program in Invisible Inc]

I can't seem to find any and solid information for this, so I *assume* the range for other sounds you can make is probably the same.

Comment: Experimented  a little bit with this in the starting mission, and this holds true for sprinting as well. In fact looks like the detection range of sprinting is indicating by the white circle you see coming out from both your character and guards.